# Rules of Inference

Tags: logic

Have a couple of questions...

How do I show invalid arguments?

> If $x$ is a real number such that $x > 1$, then $x^2 > 1$.

Suppose that $x^2$ is $> 1$, then $x > 1$. Okay, I know that this is wrong due to 
$P \rightarrow Q$,
$ Q$,
therefore $P$... is invalid, but how do I show or verify this?

Answer (score 1):

From Propositional Logic, $P \rightarrow Q \vdash \lnot Q \rightarrow \lnot P$, but the inference from "$P \rightarrow Q$" to "$Q \rightarrow P$" is NOT correct.

"The fallacy of affirming the consequent" is the following WRONG proof : assuming the fallacious $( P \rightarrow Q ) \rightarrow ( Q \rightarrow P )$, you can have :

1. "$P \rightarrow Q$" --- assumption
2. $Q$ --- assumption
3. $( P \rightarrow Q ) \rightarrow ( Q \rightarrow P )$ --- *fallacious !!*
4. $P$ --- from 3 with 1&2 and two applications of ($\rightarrow$-elimination)

Answer (score 0):

The formal definition of an invalid argument ( or, equivalently, of an invalidation of an argument) is that there is an assignment( example) where the premises are true, but the conclusion is false. So, in case you want, e.g., to show that $x^2>1 \rightarrow  x>1$ is false, then you just find a case where $x^2>1$ *but* $x \leq 1$. An invalid argument is one where the premises are true, but the conclusion is false.

So, if you wanted to show your argument is valid, you must show that, whenever $x^2>1$, it must be the case that $x>1$. If this does *not* hold, then you can show that the argument is *not* valid by giving an example of a number $x$ , where $x^2>1$, *but* $x \leq 1$ (notice that $x\leq 1$ is the negation of $x>1$).

EDIT: the converse of the statement $x>1$ , then $x^2>1$ is the statement: if $x^2 >1$ , then $x>1$ is false; take the example of $x=-2$. Then $x^2=4>1$ , but $-2 \leq -1$ . So you showed the converse is invalid , by showing there is a case where the premise $x^2>1$is true, but the conclusion is false.

Comment: Ok, so are you saying this is valid? The actual question asks me to determine if the arguments are valid. If the argument is correct then show what rule of inference is being used. Or show what logical error occurs. Reading the book, it shows that if P -> Q, Q, therefore P is not valid using a truth table. I used x^2 as P, and x > 1 as Q. I still don't know where to show what errors occur, unless there is a rule of inference to prove this.

Comment: @Rick Sanchez: Please see the paragraph I just added and let me know if that works.

Comment: Ok, I understand what you're saying, but the book is confusing me. It talks about "the fallacy of affirming the consequent" where in the 3rd row of the truth table, two premises may be true, but the conclusion might be false. I know there is number to prove it, but I'm just confused by the book where it says the argument form is invalid due to the truth table... And I'm going crazy because there is no number for me to disprove that. The truth table uses [(P -> Q) ^ Q] -> P and that's where the truth table's third row brings up a F.

Comment: I reedited; I think this addresses your questions.

Comment: http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Invalid_Argument seems to disagree with your definition.  By the link, the statement "2 is even $\rightarrow$ real numbers are happy" is an invalid argument, but not by what you stated above.  The definitions only seem to match in a complete logic.

Comment: Actually I think I found where it becomes invalid. I overlooked "real" numbers. That means .99^2 > 1 but .99 < 1. Thanks all!

Comment: Sorry, Rick, but $.99^2 =.9801 <1 $. Try with $x= -1.1$ , like I suggested. Then $(-1.1)^2=1.21>1 $ , but $(-1.1)<1$.

Comment: awesome guys! thanks